# How to use CSS selector to select div before a div

Tags: css

Ok, so i have 2 divs: "imgforplaces_thumbnailwrapper" and "checkbutton". I want to make such that when i hover to "imgforplaces_thumbnailwrapper", both "imgforplaces_thumbnailwrapper" and "checkbutton" would change to opacity 0.5. when i hover to "checkbutton", "checkbutton" would change to opacity 1, while "imgforplaces_thumbnailwrapper" opacity would change back to 0.5.

It function well when i hover to "imgforplaces_thumbnailwrapper", however, when i hover to "checkbutton", "imgforplaces_thumbnailwrapper" doesnt change back to opacity 0.5! Now i know what is the reason, that CSS doesn't have a previous selector, how do i use javascript to do this?

```
.imgforplaces_thumbnailwrapper:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;   
    }

.imgforplaces_thumbnailwrapper:hover ~ .checkbutton {
    opacity: 0.5;
}   

.checkbutton:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}    

.checkbutton:hover ~ .imgforplaces_thumbnailwrapper { //this will not work because previous selector is not available
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

things worth to note is that i wrote a javascript hover function that "checkbutton" will show(originally display:none) when i hover to "imgforplaces_thumbnailwrapper". (this works well)

my divs:

```
echo '<div class=container>';
echo '<div class=imgforplaces_thumbnailwrapper>';
        echo "<a class='ajax' href='image_color_box.php?id=".$row['id']."' title='Home'>";
        echo "<img src='../imgforplaces_thumbnail/" . $row['location_name'] . ".png' />";
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class=checkbutton><img src="../images/haventchecked.png" /></div>';
echo '</div>'; //end div container
```

Comment: which is the order of your elements? you are using A ~ B and B ~ A, one of this is wrong. A ~ B means that B is after A.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a common class shared between the two elements, lets call it "sharedclass". Then try the following CSS:

```
.sharedclass:hover{
     opacity:0.5;
}
.checkbutton:hover{
     opacity:1;
}
```

Make sure to place the checkbutton rule after the sharedclass rule, as it will overwrite the 50% opacity.

Answer (score 0):

The `~` CSS selector you're using is for matching siblings that come **after** a given element. So since `.imgforplaces_thumbnailwrapper` comes before `.checkbox`, `.checkbutton:hover ~ .imgforplaces_thumbnailwrapper` won't work as you're expecting.

This [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) article goes into detail about the general sibling combinator.

Comment: it seems that css doesn't have a selector that would select the previous element. How do i go about doing this without using css?

Comment: You could implement the behavior you want with JavaScript. If you're interested, I can edit my answer to provide a pure JavaScript solution and a jQuery solution.